# Java-ml Clustering Distance from Centriod

Tags: java, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

In python in sklearn when something is clustered you could the ["inertia"](http://www.scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans) of the clustering, which is the sum of the distance between the points to the cluster center using the chosen distance metric.

Is there an equivalent for java-ml? And if there isn't do any of you know how I should go about implementing it?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the **source code** they don't compute this value for you.

So you will have to recompute it yourself.

You could try ELKI, which has tons more options (plus, the last two java-ml versions were in 2009 and 2012 - it seems to be rather dead).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, however ELKI recommends not to use their library for on the fly programming, do you have another library you could recommend (either in java or python) where you could set the distance function and programmatically implement it?

Comment: Also does ELKI compute the inertia? If not how do you recommend I should go about it?

Comment: I'm using ELKI a lot this way and it works great. But the API still changes every version because it grows functionality.

Comment: @benjrei We do not recommend _embedding_ ELKI in a larger product because we change the API in every release (it's not version 1.0 yet). Using it for "on the fly" experiments is fine. Not all k-means variants will compute inertia - some of the fastest versions do not _have_ this value. But the basic versions do have it, and you can access it via the [KMeansModel.varsum](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/releases/release0.7.1/doc/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/data/model/KMeansModel.html#varsum) of *each* cluster (you need to compute that final sum yourself), or from the log (`-time`).